# How is add1 being used in this Racket program?

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to understand how add1 is being used in this recursion example:

```
(define (my-length a-list)
  (if (empty? a-list)
      0
      (add1(my-length (rest a-list)))))
```

If given `(my-list '(1 2 3 4))` the program will return the number 4.

I understand that after each iteration of the function `my-lenght` the code will take apart the list until the list is empty. What I don't understand is how is it that `(add1)` adds each iteration to the function.

Comment: I think the other answers answer this enough, but based on your comments I wonder if this might help:  `(add1 ...) === (+ 1 ...)`. So, `(length l) === (+ 1 (length (rest l)))` if `l` is a non-empty list, and `0` if `l` is the empty list.   So `(length '(x y z)) === (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 0))) === 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of another explanation:

This is where we start

```
(my-length '(a b c d))
```

By filling in the argument into the function, that turns into

```
(if (empty? '(a b c d))
  0
  (add1 (my-length (rest '(a b c d)))))
```

Obviously, `'(a b c d)` isn't empty. So the "else" case of the if is evaluated:

```
(add1 (my-length (rest '(a b c d))))
(add1 (my-length '(b c d)))
```

Now, what does `(my-length '(b c d))` mean? Well, if we copy paste the body of the function into our last line, we get:

```
(add1 (if (empty? '(b c d))
        0
        (add1 (my-length (rest '(b c d))))))
```

Continuing...

```
(add1 (add1 (my-length (rest '(b c d)))))
(add1 (add1 (my-length '(c d))))
```

This continues until we get an empty list:

```
(add1 (add1 (add1 (add1 (if (empty? '())
                              0
                              (add1 (my-length (rest '()))))))))
```

`'()` is empty, so the if statement returns a 0:

```
(add1 (add1 (add1 (add1 0))))
(add1 (add1 (add1 1)))
(add1 (add1 2))
(add1 3)
4
```

It's like we're diving into the function further and further, because for each step we take, we need to go one more to actually evaluate what we have.

---

How is this different from `(add1 '(a b c d))`? You can see from how the evaluation played out that `add1` was never actually applied to a, b, c or d. We never even checked to see what was in the list. You could've had a list of four lists, that each contained lists of lists, and it would evaluate all the same.

Specifically, saying `(add1 '(a b c d))` is like saying "What's 1 plus strawberry?", while your function is more like:

"How many things are in this list?"

"Well, if you don't see anything on top (`(first my-list)`), then there's definitely none."

"Okay, well...I see an "a" on top!"

"Nice! Take it out. That's at least 1 in the list."

"Okay, but how many are in the rest?"

"How about we try the same thing again? Just keep taking items out from the top of the list until the list is empty. Then, we'll put it back together, and count as we go."

"Okay, I've taken them all out. I'm going to put them back in now: d, that's 1; c, that's 2; b, that's 3; and a, that makes 4!"

"There you go, 4 in the list!"

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is recursion, I suggest you `trace` the repeated calls to `my-length`.
For example in DrRacket, write the following in the definition window:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/trace)

(define (my-length a-list)
  (if (empty? a-list)
      0
      (add1(my-length (rest a-list)))))

(trace my-length)
(my-length '(a b c d))
```

Hit `Run` and observe:

```
>(my-length '(a b c d))
> (my-length '(b c d))
> >(my-length '(c d))
> > (my-length '(d))
> > >(my-length '())
< < <0
< < 1
< <2
< 3
<4
4
```

You can see that `(my-length '(a b c d))` calls `(my-length '(b c d))` (because that's what `(rest '(a b c d))` is), which calls `(my-length '(c d))` and so on. When `(my-length '())` is called, it returns 0 (first branch of the `if`). This return value is given (returned) to the previous call, that of `(my-length '(d))`, which `add1`s to it, and so returns 1. This latter return value is returned to `(my-length '(c d))`, which returns 2 and so on until `(my-length '(a b c d))` which finally returns 4.

The crucial point here is that `add1` is apply to the return value of the recursive call, and thus has to wait for this call to return before being able to do something with this return value. In other words, the `add1`s are applied in reverse order compared to how the list is processed.

See [`racket/trace`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/debugging.html#%28mod-path._racket%2Ftrace%29) for more info and examples.

Answer (score 0):

`add1` adds `1` to its argument and returns that sum. So if the length of the rest of the list is `3`, `(add1 (my-length (rest a-list)))` will add `1` to `3` and return `4`.

In the base case of an empty list, `my-length` returns `0`.

`(my-length '(4))` calls `(my-length '())` in the recursion, which returns `0`, then calls `add1` on this to return `1`.

`(my-length '(3 4))` calls `(my-length '(4))` in the recursion. As stated above, this returns `1`, it then calls `add1` on this, which returns `2`.

and so on.

Comment: I am still having a hard time trying to picture what keeps a counter of how many times (add1) iterates. On your last example you said that it returns 1 because of the returned 0, how is (my-list) getting a 0? If the code iterates until the list given to my-list is empty, wouldn't that mean that then(empty? a-list) would return 0 therefore exiting the code?

Comment: It seems like you don't understand recursion. Each sublist is a separate call to `my-length`. It returns a value to the call with the longer list.

Comment: I really don't, I am a beginner at programming. I normally explain that on my initial posts but it gets edited out sometimes so I started not doing it. I am currently using "Realm of Racket". I have taken some basic programming classes but still have trouble understanding certain concepts such as recursion which is very new to me.

Comment: If you still don't get it, I suggest you go back to the textbook and reread the section on recursion. It's an important concept that all programmers need to understand.

Comment: I currently am. I normally stay put on concepts I don't understand until I have a useful understanding of them. For some reason I am having an incredible hard time trying to understand this particular one. It appreciate the effort in trying to help a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation is as follows:

```
   (my-list '(1 2 3 4))
-> (add1 (my-list '(2 3 4)))
-> (add1 (add1 (my-list '(3 4))))
-> (add1 (add1 (add1 (my-list '(4)))))
-> (add1 (add1 (add1 (add1 (my-list '())))))
-> (add1 (add1 (add1 (add1 0))))
-> (add1 (add1 (add1 1)))
-> (add1 (add1 2))
-> (add1 3)
-> 4
```

Comment: Which is the same explanation presented in the book. I am still having a hard time trying to understand how is it that (add1) is repeating over each iteration of my-list without throwing an error for the beginning for trying to add a number to a list. If I create a list such as (define a-lista '(1 2 3 4)) and then try to add1 on it as (add1 a-lista) it would only give me an error. How is it then that it doesn't evaluate at the same time that my-list is being evaluated on it's inner level?

Comment: @Alex_adl04 You're right that `(add1 '(1 2 3 4))` would be an error.  Fortunately that never happens, though.  If the argument is `(1 2 3 4)`, then you'll evaluate the *else* part of the `if`, which is `(add1 (my-length (rest '(1 2 3 4))))`.  Without worrying about *how* it does it, you should see that `(my-length (rest '(1 2 3 4)))` should return `3`.  If it does, then you end up calling `(add1 3)`, which is `4`.  `add1` is never called with a list;  it's only called with numbers.